# How to identify if an application is running on WebLogic or JBoss?

Tags: java, server, jboss, weblogic

On the basis of which instance an application running (like WebLogic or JBoss), I have to fetch the IP, which is mapped with a different header. So how I can identify programmatically with Java if a webapp is running on WebLogic or JBoss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to get the `jboss.server.name` system property (so you know your app is running in a JBoss container) and the `weblogic.Name` one (for the WebLogic version).

Ex.

```
String weblogicServerName = System.getProperty("weblogic.Name");
String jbossServerName = System.getProperty("jboss.server.name");
```

The one set identify your container.